# Set and fetch bindModel query in cake template file

Tags: mysql, arrays, cakephp

$categ = $this->FreeadsCategory->bindModel( array( 'hasMany' => array( 'Subcategory' => array('foreignKey' => 'category_id', 'order'=>'id ASC') ) ) );

$data = $this->FreeadsCategory->findById($i);
$this->set("datas", $data);

1. I am not able to fetch the datas in view page using cakephp
2. If i give pr($datas); showing nothing in ctp file
3. If i print the data in controller i am getting the following array structure

Array
(
    [FreeadsCategory] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [uuid] => 51512434-e4c4-441b-b90e-16f8732d5573
            [category] => Automobiles
            [status] => Active
        )

```
[Subcategory] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [uuid] => 4ea15f22-adf0-4020-b35d1-052ff9ff9a27
                [category_id] => 1
                [subcategory] => Cars/Cabs/Jeeps
                [status] => Active
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [uuid] => 51cec363-e7ac-4095-a86b-0ccdf260d1b4
                [category_id] => 1
                [subcategory] => Buses/Lorries
                [status] => Active
            )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

You don't fetch data in views, that violates the MVC pattern. Technically there are ways to do it but it's plain wrong, you'll end up with unmaintanable garbage code.

I really recommend you to get started by [reading about the MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and to do [the CakePHP blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) first to get a minimum of understanding of how CakePHP works.

Comment: $data = $this->FreeadsCategory->findById($i); 

$this->set("datas", $data);

i have to get like 
foreach($data as $d ) { 
//function
}

its giving empty event not printing array() i want to know that.

Previously i have experience in CakePHP.